# AutoMapper issue when mapping back to DTO from ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

Im having a problem in mapping back to DTO.

DTO  :

```
public class ServiceEntity : BaseChild
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class BaseChild
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public string BkName { get; set; }
    public int BkPrice { get; set; }
    public string BkDescription { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel :

```
public class BusinessEntity 
{
    public ChildBussiness Details { get; set; }
}

public class ChildBussiness
{
    public string NameFirst { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Books BookDetails { get; set; }
    public string Salary { get; set; }
}

public class Books
{
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    public int BookPrice { get; set; }
    public string BookDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

For Mapping from DTO To ViewModel im using the below code, and its working fine.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ServiceEntity obj = GetData();
    Mapper.CreateMap<ServiceEntity, BusinessEntity>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Details, o => o.MapFrom(x => new ChildBussiness { NameFirst = x.FirstName, LastName = x.LastName, Salary = x.Salary.ToString(), BookDetails = new Books { BookDescription = x.BkDescription, BookName = x.BkName, BookPrice = x.BkPrice }}));

    BusinessEntity objDetails = Mapper.Map<ServiceEntity, BusinessEntity>(obj);
}
```

While converting back im not able to do. Below code i tried.

```
.
.
.
ServiceEntity objser = new ServiceEntity();

Mapper.CreateMap<BusinessEntity, ServiceEntity>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Books, ServiceEntity>();

objser = Mapper.Map<BusinessEntity, ServiceEntity>(model);
.
.
.
```

But i didnt get any success. For an example i provided few properties. I real time i might have more than 30 property.
Any suggestion would be appreciated...

Comment: Do you get any errors or just empty properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** Thus you can change `BusinessEntity` implementation, you can use power of AutoMapper conventions and flattening. Here is modified business entity:

```
public class BusinessEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } // Instead of NameFirst
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Book Bk { get; set; } // Bk instead of BookDetails
    public string Salary { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; } // No prefixes
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

You need `Bk` name to allow flattening of `Bk.Name` to `BkName`. Now all mappings will be generated in several lines:

```
// For mapping from service entity to book
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.RecognizePrefixes("Bk"));

Mapper.CreateMap<BusinessEntity, ServiceEntity>();

// Trick to un-flatten service entity
// It is mapped both to Book and BusinessEnity
Mapper.CreateMap<ServiceEntity, Book>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ServiceEntity, BusinessEntity>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Bk, m => m.MapFrom(s => s));
```

That's it. All 30 properties will be mapped by convention:

```
var service = new ServiceEntity {
    FirstName = "Sergey",
    LastName = "Berezovskiy",
    Salary = 5000,
    BkName = "Laziness in Action",
    BkDescription = "...",
    BkPrice = 42
};

var business = Mapper.Map<BusinessEntity>(source);
var anotherService = Mapper.Map<ServiceEntity>(business);
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER** Thus you are using custom mapping, from service entity to business entity, then default mapping also will not work for backward mapping. You should manually provide mappings for members:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<BusinessEntity, ServiceEntity>()
    .ForMember(d => d.FirstName, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.Details.NameFirst))
    .ForMember(d => d.LastName, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.Details.LastName))
    .ForMember(d => d.Salary, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.Details.Salary))
    .ForMember(d => d.BkName, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.Details.BookDetails.BookName))
    .ForMember(d => d.BkPrice, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.Details.BookDetails.BookPrice))
    .ForMember(d => d.BkDescription, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.Details.BookDetails.BookDescription));
```

But I think manual mapping is better in this case, then providing all this maps for individual properties.

Comment: If im mapping for all the property, then why should i use AutoMapper, instead of that i can directly bind by creating instance.

Comment: @user2640897 that's why I wrote *"But I think manual mapping is better in this case"*

Comment: I found one more solution. I just inherited ChildBussiness in BUsinessEntity & Mapped accordingly instead of using property in Business Entity. Its works out.

Comment: @Vino thus you can edit business entities, then you can use my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the solution lazyberezovsky. Above solution seems to be like what i have implemented now. I have inherited childbusiness in BussinessEntity & used accordingly.

Comment: @Vino inheritance is a very small part of solution. Simple inheritance will not do anything with book mapping - it will deal only with two fields of business entity